# Google font does not work in IOS system, such as iPad and iPhone

Tags: ios, ipad, google-font-api

Recenetly, I try to use React.js, webpack and Google fonts to build my website.
I download fonts from this website.
[Google-webfonts-helper](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts/amatic-sc?subsets=latin-ext,latin)
The fonts I used does work in windows and android system.
However, It does not in iOS system.
[My Web3D in git-page](https://iceleaf97.github.io/NewWebsite/WebUI/index.html)
Is there any method to solve my question?

Comment: It doesn't work on my Windows 10 machine, neither in Safari, Firefox nor Edge.

Comment: That is weird. It does work in Microsoft Edge, Firefox, Chrome, even Brave browser on my computer with Windows 10 system.

Comment: Do you have the relevant fonts installed in Windows? If so, the behavior is different from devices that don't have the font installed and need to specifically download it for the web page.

Comment: I can see the Google font showed on the browser, so I do not install it in my computer.....><